# Visual Studio - getElementsByTagName() -

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio

I am brand new with Visual Basic and am looking to create a program that loads up a browser and logs you in to a specific site.

However, the username and password fields of the web site that I am attempting to log into have no id or name to pull by.

Is there a way to `GetElementByClass`?
Any help is appreciated. I cannot seem to find much documentation online.

Similar to:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("Value",yourUsername)
```

For example, the input box I am trying to get is:

```
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox" maxlength="50" style="width: 180px;">
```

So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection

Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString

'MessageBox.Show(curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString)
' This shows classNames of gwt-TextBox and gwt-PasswordTextBox

Dim user As String = "user"
Dim pass As String = "pass"

WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("gwtTextBox").SetAttribute("value", user)
WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("gwt-PasswordTextBox").SetAttribute("value", user)
```

I am now seeing that `SetAttribute` is not a member of `HtmlElement` Collection.

Comment: That's an `<input>` element. Use [.GetElementsByTagName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to enumerate them. Cycle through the enumeration to single out the one which has the class attribute you seek.

Comment: Please bear with me as this is not meant to be clean code, but this is what I came up with. Post updated. Still need assistance.

Comment: The attribute is called `className`. To write exactly as it is written here.

Comment: That did it! Now, I need to find out how to update the inputBox's with my variables. 
I will work on it and let you know if I get stuck. Thank you so much.

Comment: That one is the element `value` :)

Comment: Im unsure how to combine these two together. Still working on it >.<

Comment: I have updated the code again. It states that SetAttribute is not a member of HtmlElementCollection?

Comment: `SetAttribute()` is used to set an attribute value of a single `HtmlElement`. In your loop, identify the element with the right `className`, then set its new value. Last hint, the warning about long conversation has arrived. If you can't come up with some working code, let me know and I'll post an example.

Comment: My research is leading me in circles. It looks like an array is created and the value of each curElement is being added to theElementCollection, but i am unsure how to access them individually and set the value of each inputBox on the page. :[

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177690/discussion-between-cody-macleod-and-jimi).

Answer (score 0):

Full Code, with help of @Jimi (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)

```
   Dim inputElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    inputElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

    Dim buttonCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    buttonCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")

    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In inputElementCollection
        Dim inputName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString
        'MessageBox.Show(curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString)
        'gwt-TextBox
        'gwt-PasswordTextBox

        Dim username = uname.Text
        Dim password = passwd.Text

        If curElement.GetAttribute("className") = "gwt-TextBox" Then
            curElement.SetAttribute("value", username)
        End If

        If curElement.GetAttribute("className") = "gwt-PasswordTextBox" Then
            curElement.SetAttribute("value", password)
        End If
    Next

    For Each button As HtmlElement In buttonCollection
        Dim buttonName As String = button.GetAttribute("className").ToString

        If button.GetAttribute("className") = "gwt-Button" Then
            button.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```